# Write to Excel range from Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am looking for a way to write to an Excel range if certain values are found. What I have below keeps giving me the following error:

```
Exception setting "Range": "Cannot find an overload for "Range" and the argument count: "2
"."
At J:\ScriptTools\PowerShellScripts\Test-Excel.ps1:13 char:18
+         $ws.Range <<<< ("A1","A10")="ControlDept"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterParameterizedPropertySetValue
```

My code is below:

```
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$wb=$xl.WorkBooks.Open('C:\Temp\Test.xlsx')
$SheetName = "Sheet1"
$ws=$wb.sheets.item($SheetName)
$xl.Visible=$true
$testCell = $ws.Range("A1","A10").Text
if ($testCell -eq "MG" -or "1"){
$ws.Range("A1","A10")="ControlDept"}
$wb.Save
$xl.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have one argument that uses a colon rather than two arguments separated by a comma.

$ws.Range("A1:A10").Text